# What is the most efficient way to extend the behaviour of InputStreamReader?

Tags: java

I basically have in a project these lines of code which copies an input stream into an input stream reader so it can be streamed independently:

```
final InputStream stream = new InputStream(this.in);    
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(stream, baos);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
baos.close();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

It is working fine but I would like to encapsulate this code into an object, for instance an "InputStreamReaderCopy", which would extend InputStreamReader so it can be used exactly like it.

I wanted first to code something like this:

```
public class InputStreamReaderCopy extends InputStreamReader {
    public InputStreamReaderCopy(InputStream inputStream, String encoding) throws IOException{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, baos);
        InputStream newInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();
        super(newInputStream, encoding);
    }
}
```

But as you might expect, it is not possible to call super() after something else in the constructor.

I finally ended by having a private member

```
private InputStreamReader reader;
```

And using delegate methods of InputStreamReader and calling these king of things

```
@Override
public int read(CharBuffer target) throws IOException {
    return reader.read(target);
}
```

The problem of that is that I need to call

```
super(inputStream);
```

In the first line of my constructor even if does not make any sense (as all overidden methods are calling methods of the private member).
Is there any way to make this code more elegant ? Should I simply avoid extending InputStreamReader ?

**IMPLEMENTATION OF ANSWER BY @maxime.bochon (that suits me well)**

```
public class InputStreamReaderCopy extends InputStreamReader {

    private static InputStream createInputStreamCopy(InputStream inputStream )throws IOException{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, baos);
        InputStream newInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();
        return newInputStream;
    }

    public InputStreamReaderCopy(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        super(createInputStreamCopy(inputStream), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could extend `Reader` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "can be streamed independently"?  The purpose of streams is to be able to process data as it arrives.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would like to have two readers reading the same thing, and that calling read() on the first one does not affect the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the code creating the `InputStream` in a `private static` method. You should then be able to put the `super` call in first place with a method call as a first parameter. *This is for the first part of your question...*

Comment: I edited my question with the implementation of your answer. Thanks.